# split subdirectory off git repo with ancestors

Tags: git

One can find out several ways to split off a subdirectory of a git repo into a separate repo,
but I found nothing to do so including all ancestors which were not in that directory.

Is there a way to include these foreign ancestors?

Comment: Notoriously, git doesn't track renames directly, so identifying the ancestor of a file with a different name is a bit tricky. Some more details about the scenario might help find solutions - for instance, is there a specific list of old names that you would need to keep, or some pattern to the renames that have taken place?

Comment: Happy to hear a comment.. no, the repo as such is quite old.. it originated in cvs then moved to svn and finally to git. 
I could only find out manually tracing the commit comments...